# Get picture as http GET response and insert to spreadsheet without saving the picture

Tags: image, rest, excel, vba

I'm using the following code to get a picture from the bing map website and insert it to the spreadsheet:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim FileNum As Long
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim FileData() As Byte
    Dim winHttpReq As Object
    Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    myURL = "..."

    winHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
    winHttpReq.Send

    FileData = winHttpReq.ResponseBody

    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open "C:\Downloads\map.JPG" For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
    Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
    Close #FileNum

    InsertPic
End Sub

Sub InsertPic()
    Dim pic As String
    Dim myPicture As Picture

    pic = "C:\Downloads\map.JPG"
    Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic)

    With myPicture
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(33, 10).Top
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(33, 10).Left
    End With
End Sub
```

Is there a way to do the same without saving the picture on the local storage?

Comment: quick question. why is saving a problem? you could save it to a user's temp folder? Let me know if you want an example?

Comment: I just prefer not to if possible. Seems faster and less error prone. If there's no other way I will do it. But shoudn't there be a way?

Comment: faster maybe but less error prone? how?

Comment: To write to users temp directory you do not need special permissions like you may need for "C:\Downloads"

Comment: because you don't have to mess with the file system :)

Comment: Who says writing to temp directory will mess with the filesystem?

Comment: I'm just saying that since I don't actually need to store the file I prefer not to, unless I have to.

Comment: `I'm just saying that since I don't actually need to store the file I prefer not to, unless I have to.` I can accept this reason but saying that it is less error prone or it will mess the filesystem doesn't make sense to me :)

Comment: I just used "mess with" as an expression, just meant that I don't want to have to deal with it unless I have to :) sorry for not being clear on that :)

Comment: Can you share the URL? I would like to experiment with it...

Comment: Maybe another question will clear this issue for me: does every picture which is embedded in the spreadsheet must be stored in the file system?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't publish it since it's a trial key my tutor got from bing maps... everyone can get it but you don't have to put too much effort into it, really. I'll just use a temp file if I'll have to. I appreciate the effort though :)

Comment: Ok I have been testing it and it is possible to insert picture without saving the file. Posting my answer in few minutes. it's gonna be a long post so you will have to be patient with it :D

Comment: + 1 For managing to make me think! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm just saying that since I don't actually need to store the file I prefer not to, unless I have to.

I hate to give up! Though I still feel (*as I mentioned in my comments above*) that saving the file to user's temp directory is a simple and easy way to go about it. In fact I will mention both the methods for you.

To test this example, create a userform in Excel. Next, do this.

1. Place a TextBox, Image and a Commandbutton control in it.
2. next add the inet control. For this you will have to go via additional controls and set a reference to `Microsoft Internet Transfer Control` Your userform will look like this.

[image]

Next run the userform and then paste the URL of the image in the textbox. I am testing it with `http://static.freepik.com/free-photo/thumbs-up-smiley_17-1218174614.jpg`

When you click on the commandbutton, the image will populate in the image control.

[image]

**Logic**:

What the code does is uses the inet control to retrieve the image in the URL and then store it in a `byte` array (*instead of a directory as you requested*). I then take that byte array and convert that into an image inmemory and then assign it to the image control.

**Userform Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type GUID
  Data1 As Long
  Data2 As Integer
  Data3 As Integer
  Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Declare Function CreateStreamOnHGlobal Lib "ole32.dll" _
(ByRef hGlobal As Any, ByVal fDeleteOnResume As Long, ByRef ppstr As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function OleLoadPicture Lib "olepro32.dll" _
(ByVal lpStream As IUnknown, ByVal lSize As Long, ByVal fRunMode As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, ByRef lplpObj As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function CLSIDFromString Lib "ole32.dll" _
(ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef pclsid As GUID) As Long

Private Const SIPICTURE As String = "{7BF80980-BF32-101A-8BBB-00AA00300CAB}"

Dim boolSuccess As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim ipic As IPictureDisp

    URL = TextBox1.Text

    '~~> Store the image from the url in a bytes array
    bytes() = Inet1.OpenURL(URL, icByteArray)

    '~~> Convert Byte Array into Image
    Set ipic = ImageFromByteAr(bytes)

    Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch

    If boolSuccess = True Then
        '~~> Load Picture
        Image1.Picture = ipic
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to convert to picture"
    End If
End Sub

Public Function ImageFromByteAr(ByRef byt() As Byte) As IPicture
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Dim ippstr As IUnknown
    Dim tGuid As GUID

    If Not CreateStreamOnHGlobal(byt(LBound(byt)), False, ippstr) Then
        CLSIDFromString StrPtr(SIPICTURE), tGuid
        OleLoadPicture ippstr, UBound(byt) - LBound(byt) + 1, False, tGuid, ImageFromByteAr
    End If

    Set ippstr = Nothing

    boolSuccess = True
    Exit Function
Whoa:
    boolSuccess = False
End Function
```

---

And this is **METHOD 2** (The simplest way)

Saving the file to user's temp directory

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function

Public Sub Test()
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '

    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open TempPath & "\map.JPG" For Binary Access Write As #FileNum

    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
End Sub

Sub InsertPic()
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '

    Dim pic As String
    Dim myPicture As Picture

    pic = TempPath & "\map.JPG"
    Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic)

    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and effort, I really appreciate this a lot ! :)

Comment: @siddharth rout That's fantastic - loving Part A, tried to convert to 64 bit but failing - figured asking a new question is the wrong move, is it rude to request an answer update for 64 bit compatibility?  TIA

Answer (score 2):

If you have the URL, then:

```
Sub PictureGrabber()
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures
        .Insert ("http://www.cnn.com/whatever.jpg")
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT #1**:

For some sample coding using winHttpReq, check out [first function here](http://www.sebsworld.net/information/?page=VBScript-URL)

Comment: NO, I don't have a URL, as I wrote I'm getting the image as an http response.

Comment: But can you get the URL as a string from **winHttpReq** ?

Comment: can I? I know nothing about REST so forgive my ignorance - but the response contains a URL which looks like: .../.../maps.jpg? if so do you know how to extract it?

Comment: If you have the full response, perhaps we can parse it and extract the string.

Comment: but isn't there a simpler way? can't I somehow write the binary data into a "picture variable" instead of an actual file and then insert it to the spreadsheet?

Comment: checkout the function in the link in my **EDIT #1**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: Just an absolutely minor remark: no need for parentheses here! You'll only need them for function calls - or if you want to cast the parameter to a string! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If, WRT SiddharthRout's solution, you want compatibility with 64 Bit Office then change the declaration thusly:

```
#If VBA7 Then
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateStreamOnHGlobal Lib "OLE32.DLL" (ByRef hGlobal As Any, ByVal fDeleteOnResume As Long, ByRef ppstr As Any) As Long
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleLoadPicture Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByVal lpStream As IUnknown, ByVal lSize As Long, ByVal fRunMode As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, ByRef lplpObj As Any) As Long
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function CLSIDFromString Lib "OLE32.DLL" (ByVal lpsz As LongPtr, ByRef pclsid As GUID) As Long
#Else
   Private Declare Function CreateStreamOnHGlobal Lib "OLE32.DLL" (ByRef hGlobal As Any, ByVal fDeleteOnResume As Long, ByRef ppstr As Any) As Long
   Private Declare Function OleLoadPicture Lib "olepro32.dll" (ByVal lpStream As IUnknown, ByVal lSize As Long, ByVal fRunMode As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, ByRef lplpObj As Any) As Long
   Private Declare Function CLSIDFromString Lib "OLE32.DLL" (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef pclsid As GUID) As Long
#End If
```

With thanks to Hans Passant.

Comment: Sorry I was out yesterday and didn't see your comment and solution until now. Glad you could figure it out on your own

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks, but HansPassant provided the solution in a related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406682) I got close a few times... but failed to correctly interpret the errors thrown by the VBA IDE ;-)